# Time period of bootstrap timepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

How can I set a time limitation to bootstrap-TimePicker?
For example when we have two TimePicker for start time and end time, end time can not be set to an earlier time and start time can not be set to a later time.
I am working with AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var StartTime = new Date($scope.StartTime);
var EndTime = new Date($scope.EndTime);

if (StartTime.toJSON() >= EndTime.toJSON()) {
     console.log("End time must be greater thanstart time.");
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your answer to help other users understand it.

Comment: tanks for your answer but i want a $watch function that wile change start time allow not select time higher than end time and inverse